# Using Javascript to change text Content of a button

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling

Hey guys I'm creating a social media messaging app and right now I'm on the basics of creating a button to follow people.

When you click the button, it should change the button from saying "Follow" to "UnFollow".  Then the counter for Followers should go up by 1.

So far this is my code and it's not doing anything. I'm not getting any errors but it's also not doing anything at all.

Can someone figure out what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks

network.js:

```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  document.getElementById('followButton').addEventListener('click', () => follow_user());
  
});

function follow_user() {
    const element = document.getElementById('followButton');
    element.value = "Un-Follow";
    const element2 = document.getElementById('followers');
    element2.textContent += 1;
}
```

profile.html :

```
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}
{% block body %}

  <h2>{{user.username}}'s Profile</h2>
  <p id="followers">Followers: {{user.followers}}</p>
  <p>Follows: {{user.follows}}</p>
  {% for newquery in newqueries reversed %}
            <div class="newpost"><p>{{ newquery.body }}</p><p>By: {{ newquery.username }} on: {{ newquery.timestamp }} Likes: {{ newquery.likes }}</p></div>
{% endfor %}
<input type="button" value="Follow" id="followButton">
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but quickly scanned your code with my eyes and I could see the problem here:  const element2 = document.getElementById('followers'); you try to access element  with an id 'followers' but when you look at your HTML markup there's no such element with such id, I see you use class="followers" instead, so try to change it.

Comment: I updated the code as you can see above and it's still not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is your follower count does not have an ID. You are trying to target it with `#followers`, but it only has a class `.followers`.

Your second problem is button inputs don't display textContent. They display their value.

```
const element = document.getElementById('followButton');
element.value = "Un-Follow";
```

Comment: i updated the code above and it's still not doing anything.

Comment: Maybe the problem is somewhere else, are you sure there aren't any errors in developer's console? You also have a problem here:
 document.getElementByID('followButton') it should be getElementById not getElementByID you wrote Id all in uppercase.

Comment: OK i changed that as well - still nothing. How can this be? I've used it before. How can I be sure it's using the network.js file?

Comment: {% block script %}
            <script src="{% static '../../static/network/network.js' %}"></script>
    
{% endblock %}     <--- that's on my layout.html page

Comment: Try to look at developer's console and see what errors you get because the previous errors you had caused your code to stop executing. Also we can't help with templating engine here because there's no easy way to replicate your problem, and the problem could be somewhere else.

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/ajfcs9uq/ just removed html part where templating engine is used and I see that JavaScript works, so there could be an issue related with template engine or syntax you use or lack of something here, because we don't know where the data comes from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225002/discussion-between-erasus-and-card51short).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: const element = document.getElementById("followButton").value="Un-Button Follow" i think the value should be Button in between the un and follow i.e un-follow, Note(change it to suit your code)
Check this article here: https://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsInnerHTMLDOM/index.html